# Get Text From Windows Application - Python

Tags: python, win32gui

Trying to get text from a windows application (DASTraderPro) which has multiple sub-windows. Want to loop a function in python to update this info, ideally every 0.5 seconds or more frequently. Only have a self-taught newbie/intermediate level of python, so apologize if this is a newbie question but can't find a way forward after much Googling.

I know how to screen capture and convert image to text with pytesseract but this is too slow.

I have found how to GetWindowText() with win32gui but can't figure out how to get the text inside of windows/child windows (have found some examples of SendMessage but without any explanations that I could understand).

Would appreciate any help/nudge in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: What you want to do is somewhere between hard and impossible without support from the application. Even if you figure out the resource IDs of the fields you want (assuming they are not dynamic), the code will be brittle. Even a minor upgrade to the application (like adding a new field to a window) might change everything and break the code.

Comment: Thanks. Weird how something seemingly so simple (thinking of how easy it is to scrape web-site data) can be so difficult.

Comment: If the child window has a window handle then you can use `GetWindowText` on that handle. For something like a web browser you would need UI Automation.